# HTML form to query SQL Server database

Tags: html, sql-server

I've been searching every corner of google and can't find a simple way to do this (maybe it doesn't exist?). Basically I have a SQL Server database already full of data on a remote server, I'm trying to create just a simple HMTL form that will query the database and post the results.

I would like to do it all locally to keep it secure, in other words the website only needs to work on the same machine as the SQL Server database. Is there a simple way to do this without having to resort to using PHP and downloading all the applications to make that work locally?

I've seen some promising code that utilizes VBScripting in the HTML but I can't seem to get that working for what I need. Any suggestions or references would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HTML by itself isn't dynamic and cannot communicate with SQL or anything server side, you'll need to use some sort of Stack to communicate back and forth from the client side (html page) to the server (SQL).

PHP is one of the ways you can do that. You could also use Javascript and Node.js. ASP.NET is a higher level solution which many people find easier to learn because Microsoft sets up a lot of the code for you.

Outside of actual coding, there may be some tools online that are set up to just display query data in a web format, though these will likely have a cost aspect to them.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS LINK YOU CAN USE INFOPATH TO
INSERT INTO SQL
[INFO ON SQL AND FORMS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4246/data-entry-for-sql-server-building-quick-efficient-data-input-forms-using-infopath/)

Comment: Link only answers are not recommended, [see why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/1027611)